# FirebaseMessaging Android not send message

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm try implement a app that sends messages from Android -> Android. I can send message notifications from FirebaseConsole -> Android.
I tried this:

```
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
        fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder("382106095787" + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
                .setMessageId("1")
                .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
                .addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
                .build());
```

But in the other app nothing happens. The method onMessageReceived is not call.
Another this, I don't know other way to send/receive messages in the Android Devices, like a chat app. The example from git is not clarous and I can't undertand how this works.

Comment: Hi. I would strongly suggest that you watch [Getting Started with Firebase Cloud Messaging on Android - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPpK65BX80o) and going through the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to have better understanding on the flow and behavior of FCM. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

[`FirebaseMessage.send()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream#send_an_upstream_message_from_an_android_client_app) is intended to send message(s) to an App Server, not to other Android devices. You need to implement your own App Server that handles the message and perform [downstream messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) towards the other Android devices (users) from there.

> Client apps can send upstream messages back to the app server using the XMPP-based Cloud Connection Server. For example:
>
> ```
> FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(
>  new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
>  .setMessageId(id)
>  .addData("key", "value")
>  .build());
> ```

As you can see, the example is for sending upstream messages to the server.

Comment: Where I found examples about how to implement a App Server? I follow some tutorials that works with node.js and deploy app with CLI, but not works for me.